# Passing config values to OWASP ZAP rest api script as a file: format?

Tags: rest, owasp, penetration-testing, zap

I wanted to automate API pentesting.

I referred this blog:

https://zaproxy.blogspot.in/2017/06/scanning-apis-with-zap.html

Could you direct me to where I can get a sample zap-options file that we pass with -z option to the zap-api-scan.py script, or where I can get documentation regarding the format in which config values has to be specified in the file? I could not find the official ZAP docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this FAQ https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQconfigValues - thats the best we've got at the moment I'm afraid

Comment: Can I pass a file with config values as:

config.txt
------------
`-config formhandler.fields.field\(0\).fieldId=username \ # do i need "\" inside a config file`

OR 

should these be passed in a config.xml ?

Comment: You can either pass them as -config parameters or supply them in the config file as key=values lines, as descruibed in the help file: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help/wiki/HelpCmdline#options

Comment: Thanks Simon, for pointing that out. Sorry for not picking it up from the docs.